# Spring boot Annotations keeps http data in the variables

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, spring-restcontroller, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a problem with spring boot.
It's keeps data in a class that is annotated in:

### @RestController, @Service, @Component.

I can't keep any data because it will be shared with others like a session.

Example:

```
@RestController
public class controller {

    int x = 65;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/set/{number}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int view(@PathVariable("number") int number) {
        x = number;
        return x;
    }       

    @RequestMapping(value = "/get", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public int view2() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

First call:
localhost:80802/get  Result: 65.

Second call:
localhost:8080/set/5 Result: 5

Third Call:
**localhost:8080/get Result:5**

**Third call Result Supposed to be: 65**

This situation is also happens in the other annotations that i mentioned.

Why its use @RestController class as a kind of singleton?
I cant store anything in a class that is annotated?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@Scope` annotation as described [here](http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-bean-scope-example-using-scope-annotation-and-xml-for-singleton-prototype-request-session-global-session-and-application-scope-with-scoped-proxy#session-annotation). For example:

```
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode =ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@RestController
public class controller {
....
}
```

Comment: I tried it , and it still keeps data in the "x" variable.
I want that the data won't be stored in the class there in the next http call...

Comment: I think, you must enable class proxies by adding `spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true` to `application.properties` file.

Comment: I've tried it also, and still, I don't get the initial number 65 in a "get" call, after a "set/5" call.